# How can I host JVM in a native C++ win32 application?

Tags: java

There is a [well known COM api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99sz37yh.aspx) allowing arbitrary C++ code to host a .NET runtime. Is something like this possible for a JVM runtime? I am not talking about COM API in particular, any C/C++ API will do.

Comment: AFAIK JNI can be used both to call native code from Java **and** to call Java programs from native code (a tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section3.html)

Comment: I know that. The question is not about interop, but about hosting.

Comment: The simplest way to "host" a JVM is to run a separate process.  You can do what you suggest, but it more complex and I have never seen it worth the effort involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LeleDumbo said in the comments JNI sounds like what you want.

Specifically the [Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502) [API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html) which "... allows software vendors to load the Java VM into an arbitrary native application."